# Set drawableLeft using network url

Tags: android, textview

I am working on an android app. In this application I am using a textview and setting drawableLeft property on this textview.

Now this drawable image is dynamic and coming from server, so I am not able to set it using network url. 
I have a string url and want to load the drawableLeft icon with this url, how can I do that because the images are dynamic and coming from server, I can not save these images in drawable.

Can anyone help me here, Thanks a lot in advanced.

Comment: Post your code where you download image

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
Bitmap bitmap = Your bitmap image;
Drawable imgDrawable = new BitmapDrawable(bitmap);
imgDrawable.setBounds(0, 0, bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight());
textView.setCompoundDrawables(null, imgDrawable , null, null);
```

Answer (score 0):

This tutorials may help you to solve this problem [Image gridview](http://stacktips.com/tutorials/android/android-gridview-example-building-image-gallery-in-android), [Get all images from server](https://www.simplifiedcoding.net/android-programming-tutorial-to-get-all-images-from-server/)